# ModelState.Isvalid es siempre falso

Tags: c#, mvc

mi modelo:

```
public class Unidad
{
    public int UnidadID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Unidad Abrevidad no puede ser vacio")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Display(Name ="Unidad Abrevidad")]
    public string AbbreviatedUnit { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Descripcion no puede ser vacio")]
    [StringLength(200,MinimumLength =3)]
    [Display(Name = "Descripción")]
    public string description { get; set; }

}
```

ubicado en el controlador
mi metodo delete

```
public ActionResult Delete(int id, Unidad unidad)
{
     try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                Unidad deleteunidad = TempRepository.EditOrDelete(id);
                if (deleteunidad == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                TempRepository.DeleteUnidad(deleteunidad);
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            // TODO: Add delete logic here

           return View(unidad);
        }
        catch
        {
            return View(unidad);
        }
    }
```

ubicado en la clase UnidadRepository
mi metodo encontrar unidad

```
internal Unidad FindUnidad(int? id)
    {
        using (var db = new CNRContext())
        {
            var unidad = db.Unit.Find(id);
            return unidad;
        }
    }
```

mi metodo para borrar la unidad

```
internal void DeleteUnidad(Unidad unidad)
    {
        using (var db = new CNRContext())
        {

            db.Entry(unidad).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
```

mi ModelState.IsValid es siempre falso cuando trato de borrar una unidad??

Comment: Para que el ModelState sea falso, tiene que tener un error asociado, te fijaste cual es?

Comment: El español no es mi lengua materna pero no debería ser: "Unidad Abreviada no puede estar vacía" y "Descripción no puede estar vacía"?

Comment: El problema se debe a que estás validando un modelo el cual no haces uso de él. ¿Podrías agregar el código de la vista para saber el modelo que usas?

Comment: Cuando haces un delete solo tienes que indicar el Id, no hace falta que pases la unidad. Con el Id obtienes la unidad mediante una consulta y de esta manera compruebas primero que existe y luego lo eliminas.

Comment: Excelente!!! IDanny7,  Buena Respuesta.